# Adding JS functions to a parallel queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have this code, I want to run all the database inserts and then disconnect from the database at the end of the script. The problem is that I need to execute the disconnect callback after the loop ends, but it's non-deterministic. So I would need to create a function for each of the loops, and then only after all those functions have completed, call the function to disconnect from mongoose/mongoDB.

Does anyone see the problem that I have with this code?

//this code is close, but not quite, since it will disconnect from mongo before doing very many inserts/saves

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;

var UserModel = require('../models/UserModel');
UserModel.registerSchema(mongoose);


var fs = require('fs');
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../dummy_data/dummy_user_data', 'utf8'));


var system_db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/local_dev_db');


function insertUsers(callback){


    parsedJSON.forEach(function (item, index) {

        var User = UserModel.getNewUser(system_db);

        var user = new User({
            username: item.username,
            password: item.password,
            address: item.address,
            phone: item.phone,
            email: item.email,
            gender: item.gender,
            about: item.about,
            latitude: item.latitude,
            longitude: item.longitude
        });

        user.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error in player save method:", err);
            }
            console.log(index);
            if (result) {
                //console.log('Added!', result);
            }
        });

    });
    callback();
}


function disconnect(){
    mongoose.disconnect();
    mongoose.connection
        .close(function () {

            console
                .log('Mongoose connection disconnected');

            process.exit(0);

        });
}

insertUsers(disconnect);
```

So the solution would be to use the async.parallel library, and only after all the functions are done, call a final callback function. However, how can I do that programmatically instead of putting a known group of functions into the async.parallel codeblock, I need to put an unknown number of functions into the aysnc.parallel codeblock. Ya seen?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely can be done. Just dynamically add your functions to an array that will be passed to `async.parallel`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;

var UserModel = require('../models/UserModel');
UserModel.registerSchema(mongoose);

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../dummy_data/dummy_user_data', 'utf8'));

var system_db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/local_dev_db');

var insertFunctions = [];

parsedJSON.forEach(function (item, index) {

    insertFunctions.push(function(callback) {

        var User = UserModel.getNewUser(system_db);

        var user = new User({
            username: item.username,
            password: item.password,
            address: item.address,
            phone: item.phone,
            email: item.email,
            gender: item.gender,
            about: item.about,
            latitude: item.latitude,
            longitude: item.longitude
        });

        user.save(function (err, result) {

            if (err) {
                console.log("error in player save method:", err);
                callback(err);
                return;
            }

             callback(null, result);

        });
    });
});

function disconnect() {

    mongoose.disconnect();
    mongoose.connection
        .close(function () {

            console
                .log('Mongoose connection disconnected');

            process.exit(0);
        });
}

//First parameter is the array of functions to run in parallel,
// second parameter is the callback function
async.parallel(insertFunctions, disconnect);
```

Comment: looks good, I  will take out the if(result){} block though, no need for that if IMO

Comment: actually @gregnr async.series gave me the expected console output, but for some reason async.parallel gave me very unexpected console output, not because it was unordered but because 90% of the entries were missing, that shouldn't happen. but async.series had expected output, all 100% and of course in order. why would this be?

Comment: Throw in a console.log before your user.save function and one in the callback. What kind of results do you get?

Comment: with async.parallel I get totally weird output, like 7 entries instead of 130, and the console.log output in the loop but outside the user.save never gets logged at all. With async.series, everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm suspicious something in UserModel is causing concurrency problems. Could you provide your UserModel code?

Comment: I think I know  the problem. The problem is that the insertFunctions lists is growing even after the async.series/async.parallel call is made. That means it might think it's done with all the functions, but really more functions are being added on an ongoing basis. so the final disconnect callback happens before some functions are added to the insertFunctions list. Makes sense? ...there's only one thing I can think of to get around the problem. For the last index of the loop, after that function is added then I can call another function that contains the async.series/async.parallel call. Done.

Comment: The `insertFunctions` array should not be growing after `async.parallel` is called since `forEach()` is synchronous. Do a `console.log(insertFunctions.length)` right before you call `async.parallel`. It should be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, async.each() actually fits better than async.parallel().  async.each() is parallel while async.eachSeries() is not.  Here is the code:

```
function insertUsers(callback){
  var User = UserModel.getNewUser(system_db);

  async.each(parsedJSON, function (item, eachCb) {
    var user = new User({
        username: item.username,
        password: item.password,
        address: item.address,
        phone: item.phone,
        email: item.email,
        gender: item.gender,
        about: item.about,
        latitude: item.latitude,
        longitude: item.longitude
    });

    user.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error in player save method:", err);
        }
        console.log(index);
        if (result) {
            //console.log('Added!', result);
        }
        eachCb();  // if calling with eachCb(err), async.each()
                   // will not continue the rest of the items
                   // in case of error occurs
    });

  }, function(err) {
    callback();    // done with all user.save() calls
  });
}
```